# Multiple login fields in django user

Tags: python, django

While using Django user is it possible somehow to use multiple login fields?
Like in Facebook where we can login using username, email as well as the phone number.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, it is! You can write your own authentication backend, as this section describes:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/customizing/

We suppose you have created an application account/ where you extend the User model for the additional phone field.
Create your auth backend backends.py inside account/ and write you own authentication logic. For example:

```
from account.models import UserProfile
from django.db.models import Q


class AuthBackend(object):
    supports_object_permissions = True
    supports_anonymous_user = False
    supports_inactive_user = False


    def get_user(self, user_id):
       try:
          return UserProfile.objects.get(pk=user_id)
       except UserProfile.DoesNotExist:
          return None


    def authenticate(self, username, password):
        try:
            user = UserProfile.objects.get(
                Q(username=username) | Q(email=username) | Q(phone=username)
            )
        except UserProfile.DoesNotExist:
            return None

        return user if user.check_password(password) else None
```

Put you custom backend in you project's settings.py:

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = ('account.backends.AuthBackend',)
```

Then just authenticate by passing username, email or phone in the POST's username field.

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login

def my_view(request):
    username = request.POST['username']
    password = request.POST['password']
    user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
    if user is not None:
        if user.is_active:
            login(request, user)
            # Redirect to a success page.
        else:
            # Return a 'disabled account' error message
            ...
    else:
        # Return an 'invalid login' error message.
        ...
```

see: https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/1.8/topics/auth/default/