# how to generate token using username and pin field in django auth toolkit for a phone app while keeping username and password for the web application?

Tags: django

I am using DRF with auth toolkit and it is working fine. However, I want to have a second login api so a user can log in using username and pin number. It is cos we have a USSD application and it is easier to give them a pin based login system.

Currently, I have the following URL that, when called, generates token:

```
         url(r'^signin/', include('oauth2_provider.urls', namespace='oauth2_provider')),
```

For the ussd app, I want something like that but the auth2 should check pin field, defined in a separate model defined as follows:

```
     class Members(models.Model):
         pin=models.IntegerField()
         user=models.ForeignKey(User)
```

I am a little lost where to start.

Comment: So you want to give a user two "password" fields, one which contains the web application login password and one that contains the mobile pin login? You then authenticate on the relevant password field depending on the type of login?

Comment: The pin is for a USSD version of the app cos it is easier to type in the old phones. While web application would continue to sue the standard oauth2_provider, which is currently generating correct token using username and password from User model. Now for ussd application, I want the user to generate the token from username of User model and pin field of Members which has onetoone field with User model. It is only cos entering numbers is easy on old ussd based phones plus they are used to pin on things like such mobile money services already.

Answer (score 1):

Using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30880135/3848720) as a base to answer this question, and [Django's documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/customizing/).

I would say you'd want to create a custom authentication backend, and you'd want a custom user model with two passwords, or using a one-to-one relationship to add the additional password field, something like so:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser

class UserExtension(AbstractBaseUser):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    ...
```

Inheriting from the AbstractBaseUser should add a password field like the user model, (although I haven't tried this). If you prefer the custom user approach, I actually have a [github repo](https://github.com/tdsymonds/django-custom-authentication) that has a custom user app, so if you'd like to get any ideas of how to achieve this check it out.

Or have a look through the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/customizing/#s-substituting-a-custom-user-model).

Either way, once you've got your two passwords, you need to decide which one to use as the pin. If you're using oauth for the pin field and the web applicaiton with the password, I would probably use the standard user password for the pin login, as that way you don't need to change the oauth package to work with your new password. Then for your web application build a custom login. To do this create a custom authentication backend along the lines of:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.hashers import check_password


class AuthBackend(object):
    supports_object_permissions = True
    supports_anonymous_user = False
    supports_inactive_user = False

    def get_user(self, user_id):
       return User.objects.filter(pk=user_id).first()

    def authenticate(self, username, password):
        user = User.objects.filter(username=username).first()

        if not user:
            return None

        # this is checking the password provided against the secondary password field
        return user if check_password(password, user.userextension.password) else None
```

Then you need to add this authentication backend to your settings:

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = ('myapp.backends.AuthBackend',)
```

Then create the web application login (as per the stackoverflow answer above):

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login

def my_login_view(request):
    username = request.POST['username']
    password = request.POST['password']
    user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
    if user is not None:
        if user.is_active:
            login(request, user)
            # Redirect to a success page.
        else:
            # Return a 'disabled account' error message
            ...
    else:
        # Return an 'invalid login' error message.
        ...
```

You should now have a custom authentication login for the web application using your password2 field, and you can use the oauth authentication to work with the standard Django password in which you're going to store the pin. Which I think is what you're trying to do?

*NOTE: All of the above I haven't tested, so this may not work perfectly, but it should hopefully be able to at least point you in the right direction and give you a few ideas. If I'm understanding your problem correctly, this is the sort of approach that I would take to tackle the problem.*

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation @tdsymonds. But i think this creates session based logins, right and i am looking for token based login where tokens are saved. But it does work as a session based login system, thanks. If i fail, i probably will switch to it.

Comment: No worries, but you'll have token based logins from the oauth login. The web application would be session based, but I'm not sure if you can and why you would want to make this token based, as this approach wouldn't work when a user logs in via a browser...