# Multiple Login Field Options for Django Rest Framework (JWT)

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-framework-jwt

How can I override the `django-rest-framework-jwt` `JSONWebTokenSerializer` to allow for a user to login via either email, username or password.

I see that as the suggested option [in this github issue](https://github.com/GetBlimp/django-rest-framework-jwt/issues/84) but am not sure how I'd override the default JSONWebTokenSerializer as its not among the [`JWT_AUTH`](https://getblimp.github.io/django-rest-framework-jwt/#additional-settings) settings.

I want to be able to provide functionality as seen [in this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30880135/1082673) where you can allow a Django User to login via any field you may have in the Custom user table

Answer (score 1):

For anyone using Django Allauth, adding these settings in the settings.py file solves this.

```
ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD=“username_email” 
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = True 
ACCOUNT_UNIQUE_EMAIL = True 
ACCOUNT_USERNAME_REQUIRED = True
```

All the configurations can be found [here](http://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration.html).